# SSL Hostname mismatch although CN of client and server match

Tags: ssl, openssl

I generated a ca-certificate, server-certificate and client-certificate using the guidelines of rabbitmq (https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#manual-certificate-generation)

But I keep getting an error Hostname mismatch when checking the certs with openssl s_server.

```
openssl s_server -accept 8443 -cert server_certificate.pem -key private_key.pem -CAfile ca_certificate.pem
```

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -cert client_certificate -key private_key.pem -CAfile ca_certificate.pem -verify 8 -verify_hostname CN_NAME
```

RESULT:

```
Verify return code: 62 (Hostname mismatch)
```

When I read the hostnames, they both show the same..?

```
openssl x509 -in server_certificate -subject -noout
subject=CN = MyTestCA, O = server

openssl x509 -in client_certificate -subject -noout
subject=CN = MyTestCA, O = client
```

So I'm stuck why I'm getting the error 'Hostname mismatch'?

Comment: You get a hostname mismatch if the name used to access the host (`localhost` in your case) does not match the name in the server certificate.

Comment: @steffen, I keep getting the error if I use 'localhost' or $(hostname) or $(ec2metdata --public-hostname) or the registered domain name? Tried to generate certs with 5 different CN, all give hostname mismatch.

Comment: *"Tried to generate certs with 5 different CN, all give hostname mismatch."* - please provide a) the contents of the certificate b) the command lines you've used to access the server with this specific certificate (i.e. what the hostname was). Also, the domain name should be today given as subject alternative name, not CN. And based on the current question it is not even properly given as CN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is due to using the same CN for the CA and server.
Solved it by using another CN for the CA.